# React Radio Buttons - partially working - getting data correctly - but not rendering as selected

Tags: reactjs, forms, radio-button, react-bootstrap

I'm using React and Bootstrap.  I have a from, and am using radio buttons for a multiple choice question.  The part that is working, is that it does grab the correct value when you select the radio button of your choice and save that into the state properly.

The part that isn't working, is when you click the radio button, it doesn't render correctly to show it's been selected.  It did until I added the "Value" and "Checked" properties.

I also get this warning:
*"Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`"*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Container, Form, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from "../../../../Config/Theme";

const Div = styled.div`
    background-color: white;
    color: black;

    .form-section{
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 2em;
      margin-top: 1em;
    }
`

class Culture extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      editing: false,
      editingTimeout: 0,

      formCulture1: 0
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    
    }

  handleChange(e) {
    const targetName = e.target.name;
    const targetValue = e.target.value
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
    if (this.state.editingTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.state.editingTimeout);
    }

    this.setState({
      editing: false,
      editingTimeout: setTimeout(function () {
        
      }, 300)
    });

  }


    render() {
        return (
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Div>
              <Container >
                <Form className="p-3">
                  <h4 className="py-3">Culture Development</h4>
                  <div className="form-section">
                    
                    <h5>Company Culture</h5>
                    <hr/>
                    <p className="font-italic font-weight-bold">On a scale from 1 to 5 (1-Low and 5-High)...</p>
                    <Form.Group as={Row} name="formCulture1" controlId="formCulture1" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                      <Form.Label column sm={5}>
                        1. How would you rate your company culture?
                    </Form.Label>
                      <Form.Check
                        inline
                        type="radio"
                        label="1"
                        value="1"
                        checked={this.state.formCulture1 === 1}
                        name="formCulture1"
                        id="formCulture1-1"
                      />
                      <Form.Check
                        inline
                        type="radio"
                        label="2"
                        value="2"
                        checked={this.state.formCulture1 === 2}
                        name="formCulture1"
                        id="formCulture1-2"
                      />
                      <Form.Check
                        inline
                        type="radio"
                        label="3"
                        value="3"
                        checked={this.state.formCulture1 === 3}
                        name="formCulture1"
                        id="formCulture1-3"
                      />
                      <Form.Check
                        inline
                        type="radio"
                        label="4"
                        value="4"
                        checked={this.state.formCulture1 === 4}
                        name="formCulture1"
                        id="formCulture1-4"
                      />
                      <Form.Check
                        inline
                        type="radio"
                        label="5"
                        value="5"
                        checked={this.state.formCulture1 === 5}
                        name="formCulture1"
                        id="formCulture1-5"
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </div>
                  
                </Form>
              </Container>
            </Div>
          </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default Culture;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out.  All I had to do was remove the "checked" properties from each radio button, and it fixed both the warning message and the rendering issue.